# SpringBoot JPA persist child of parent with nulls columns

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, cascade

I have strange problem. I have entity Company, Branch and Address.
Company has list of branch and every branch has address.
Im trying to persist branch with not exist before address entity, but Address is persist with nulls columns.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private String id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<Branch> branches;

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String phone;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String street;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Company company;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Branch branch;
}
```

Service ...

```
    public Integer addBranch(BranchDto branchDto) {
        Branch branch = modelMapper.map(branchDto, Branch.class);

        Company company = companyRepository.getCompanyById(branchDto.getCompanyId());
        branch.setCompany(company);

        return branchRepository.save(branch).getId();
    }
```

Dto...

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class BranchDto {

    private Integer id;

    private String phone;

    private String email;

    private AddressDto address;

    private String companyId;
}
```

And that is effect...

[image]

Debugger...

[image]

What is the problem? Can you help me ?

Comment: Look at the object identifiers in the debugger `Branch@...` and `Address@....`. Address should be same object as branch.address and address.branch.address should be same object as   Address. Your mapping code is probably messed up somewhere

Comment: I discovered that jpa has problem with persist not existed Branch which has not existed Address. So i had to persist Branch and after set Address and again persist Branch.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'mappedBy' with the same id, It only works with the first one he find.

Try to change to other id.

Comment: But why Its works for User and Company but not works for Branch ?

Comment: That is not problem, JPA is smart and understand it.